# How to add a dynamic column on the result sent by joining tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to join 6 tables. The tables are as follows.

- listings
- listingimages
- users
- cities
- states
- favlistings

listings table

- Id, User, Title,Description, Category, Type, Location,Address,City, State etc

listing images table

- Id, Listing(Id from listing table), path of image etc

Users table
 - Id and other user related details

cities and states have

- Id, Name

favlisting table

- Id, listing, User etc.

Now, my requirement:
I have to select all the data from the listing table get the state and city name depending on the id's that listing have.
I also have to select the current user details such as first & last name, till this part is easy,

Now the problem is with while joining the last table favlisting.
I have to select all the above mentioned data along with the dynamic column with yes or no scaning favlisting table.

Favlisting table keep track of all the listing that is marked as favrouite. So, it holds a listing ids which user marked as fav.

I have to scan and add new column saying Favrouite field and fill it with Y if the current user has marked the listing as fav else N for no.

How can I achieve this result.

My backend code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT a.*, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, c.Image, d.Name AS 
cityName,e.Name AS stateName, 
IF(a.Id = f.ListingId, "Y", "N") as Favourite 
FROM listings a, listingimages b, rausers c, cities d, states e, favlistings 
f 
WHERE a.Id = b.Listing AND a.Status="A" AND a.City = d.Id AND a.State = e.Id 
AND a.User = c.Id 
ORDER BY a.CreatedOn 
DESC LIMIT 20
```

I am getting the correct output however there is one problem, the record which is listed on favlisting table is showing twice with Favourite column as Y and N. It's getting duplicate.

I can see the IF case is executing first and then the conditions.

I just need the result without any duplication.

let me also tell you that this is a laravel project. I am using this query in this way.

```
public function getImages(Request $request){
    $uID=$request->id;

    $check = DB::select('SELECT * FROM favlistings');

    if(sizeof($check)>0){ 
        $data = DB::select('SELECT DISTINCT a.*, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
        c.Email, c.Image, d.Name AS cityName,e.Name AS stateName, IF(a.Id = 
        f.ListingId, "Y", "N") as Favourite 
        FROM listings a, listingimages b, rausers c, cities d, states e, 
        favlistings f 
        WHERE a.Id = b.Listing AND a.Status="A" AND a.City = d.Id AND 
        a.State = e.Id AND a.User = c.Id 
        ORDER BY a.CreatedOn DESC LIMIT 20');
    }
    else{
        $data = DB::select('SELECT DISTINCT a.*, c.FirstName, c.LastName, 
        c.Email, c.Image, d.Name AS cityName,e.Name AS stateName, IF( ? > 0, 
        "Y", "N") as Favourite 
        FROM listings a, listingimages b, rausers c, cities d, states e
        WHERE a.Id = b.Listing AND a.Status="A" AND a.City = d.Id AND 
        a.State = e.Id AND a.User = c.Id ORDER BY a.CreatedOn DESC LIMIT 
        20',[sizeof($check)]);
    }
    $Images;
    if(sizeof($data) != 0 ){
        foreach ($data as $key) {
            $Images[$key->Id] = DB::table('listingimages')-
            >where('Listing',$key->Id)->select('listingimages.Image')-
            >get();
        }
    }
    else{
        $Images = "Image Not Available";
    }

    return response()->json([
        "data",$data,
        "Images",$Images]);
}
```

[image: favlisting table]
  [image: main table listing]
  [image: users table]
  [image: favlisting data]
  [image: listing data]
  [image: user data]

Comment: Have you tried using Eloquent?

Comment: check the [unique](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-unique) helper. I did not try it for database query but i think it might help.

Comment: Without seeing table structure and data it might be hard to give an answer.  One other comment: try rewriting your query to use explicit joins.

Comment: With Elosquent I haven't tried it. That was my next approach. @Ross Wilson.

Comment: Unique seems quite close. I will try that for filtring the result. Thanks but I just wondering to know whether it can be solved with query or this might be the final optimal ans for this. @Amr Aly

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, I can understand it is difficult to answer such query without proper structure and data to help out. I will try something else and see if that works or not.

Comment: Unique seems not working with my requirement. Coz its duplicating the same row. I mean if I mark one ad as my fav, it goes and updates in favlisting table, so the final query is giving me the same record twice with last Favrouite column as Y and N. If I say Unique on Favrouite it will just give me Y and N, so, its not possible to work with unique. @Arm Aly

Comment: You can add a key to unique function for example `$collection->unique('key');` however it would be better if you mange the duplication in the selecting process. and you can achieve this using the [query builder and distinct helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries)

Comment: Don't you think while handling the output in such way will reduce the response performance? I just think it will be too heavy and this is a call that user often request for.

Comment: Of-course it will be heavy in your case i would recommend to try using the query builder

Comment: My problem will be the same, how to mark the row as Y or N adding new column as fav? It is creating 2 records with Y and N when I add a dynamic column. If you can help me out to write such query then it would be very helpful. I am not able to form that using query builder. Infact, I have never tried query builder for such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left & inner join :

```
SELECT 
a.*, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, c.Image, d.Name AS cityName,e.Name AS stateName, 
IF(a.Id = f.ListingId, "Y", "N") as Favourite 
FROM listings a
inner join listingimages b on a.Id = b.Listing
inner join rausers c on a.User = c.Id
inner join cities d on a.City = d.Id
inner join states e on a.State = e.Id
left join favlistings f on a.Id = f.listing
WHERE  a.Status="A" 
ORDER BY a.CreatedOn 
DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
a.*, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Email, c.Image, d.Name AS cityName,e.Name AS stateName, 
IF((select Id from favlistings f where a.Id = f.Listing and a.User = f.User), "Y", "N") as Favourite 
FROM listings a, listingimages b, rausers c, cities d, states e
WHERE a.Id = b.Listing AND a.Status="A" AND a.City = d.Id AND a.State = e.Id AND a.User = c.Id 
ORDER BY a.CreatedOn 
DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Akshay thank you for your time. but this approach is not working for me. And the subquery that you have written will take row from favlisting table and then creates the new column. I have to take this table just to see if the row exists or not, if the same id exists then I have to fill Y else N, this is the reason why I was creating a new column.

Comment: @kiran rai chamling, subquery is checking  the row exists in fav table or not if exist column value = 'Y' if no column value = 'N'. what is expected output? and any error in above query.

Comment: well! that's true. I have listing table and favlisting table, I can see the listings in my dashboard and mark them as fav. So, every listing will have its ids, that Id I am dumping in the favlisting table so that I can track these items on my dashboard. Now, while loading my dashboard I have to check both the tables and create new dynamic column marking particular item as fav or not. Refering table(favlisting) is used for checking this condition. Note: I have to select all the rows from parent table (listing) and mark them with Y or N if it exists in favlisting table.

Comment: can you provide sql script of table structure with data?.

Comment: Your subquery is comparing the listing id and the user Id. In fact, the user col in the listing id should not be compared. This will restrict the result with only one user. I want SELECT * from table 1 and add one dynamic col with the value Y or N just by checking the favlisting table. That's it. My query is giving me the result but it is also creating the duplicate record. lets say if there is listing with id 1 in fav listing then its creating 2 rows with Favrouite column Y and N. Row with N shouldn't repeat actually.